# Set filter for certain contacs in skype

Tags: skype

Is there a way to set filter and receive messages only from certain contacts e.g. during working hours and check the rest of the messages later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no feature in Skype (`version 6.9.0.106`) that enables you to do this. Setting your status to *Busy* is currently the closest thing that you can do. People in your contacts can still call you and send IMs, but you won't get alerted with sound.

You can, however, filter out messages based from the sender of the message.

1. From the menu bar, click **View**
2. Choose **Instant Messages** from the drop-down menu
3. Type in the search box the name of the sender you wish to check

From here, you can selectively mark the IMs you're not interested as read, to leave the ones which are more important as unread.